# Use password hash created in GO on Django admin auth doesn't work

Tags: python, django, authentication, go, pbkdf2

I'he created a func in GO to simulate the hash password construction in Django. But when i create the user and try to login in Django Admin, i receive invalid password message and the hash of password was changed in database.

The function in go to recreate de pass hash builder is:

```
func PasswordEncode(password string, salt string, iterations int) (string, error) {

    if strings.TrimSpace(salt) == "" {
        salt = CreateRandomString(12)
    }

    if strings.Contains(salt, "$") {
        return "", errors.New("salt contains dollar sign ($)")
    }

    if iterations <= 0 {
        iterations = 20000
    }

    hash := pbkdf2.Key([]byte(password), []byte(salt), iterations, sha256.Size, sha256.New)

    b64Hash := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(hash)

    return fmt.Sprintf("%s$%d$%s$%s", "pbkdf2_sha256", iterations, salt, b64Hash), nil
}

func CreateRandomString(len int) string {
    var container string
    var str = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890"
    b := bytes.NewBufferString(str)
    length := b.Len()
    bigInt := big.NewInt(int64(length))
    for i := 0; i < len; i++ {
        randomInt, _ := rand.Int(rand.Reader, bigInt)
        container += string(str[randomInt.Int64()])
    }
    return container
}
```

So i have this hash to 'example' password :

`pbkdf2_sha256$20000$rkOZv4FYyskC$gIn13Rsr229e5AbhgYDTflBWOH9k+d6wEyKPmHryIjI=`

But when i try to login in Django admin, i receive the invalid password message and the application change de hash to:

`pbkdf2_sha256$390000$M3ntXZosTvxynIk193G107$40btNBSvVzDKXlS3pbrYfxpZV8lyjsTzG+fW/PL7wCY=`

Obs.: I'he already tryied to put 22 characteres on salt build func , and set to 390000 iterations, but have the same problem with the difference that the hash is not changed.

Obs(2).: Obviusly, both of applications have the same database for users.

Comment: Did you check https://github.com/meehow/go-django-hashers?